# How to make listview.builder builder that starts from the center?

Tags: flutter

I am making an application that query data from an external database that returns a list of 100 events sorted by date. (50 future dates, 50 past dates)

The homepage would then render a Listview.builder filled with ExpansionTile to then show it to the user.

The catch is, we to set the first item on the screen to be item number 51.
That means from then, below it it would show item 52,53,54 and so.

But, when the user scrolls up, instead of trigger physics refresh typical with Listview.Builder, we hope to show item 50,49,48 and so on.

Any ideas as to how to achieve it?
The idea is to basically always show today's event initially but user can seamlessly browse future events and past events

this does not achieve the desired result as it ends up with a 'break'

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  final List<int> nums2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: nums.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text('${nums[index]}'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: nums2.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text('${nums2[index]}'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Can you show what you've did so far?

Comment: edited the message to show what i did before

Comment: If I got it correct, you have N items and want to set list to show the N/2th item in the middle, for that you can use `ScrollController` and path it to the list, [See This Example](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac)

Comment: Also consider using `ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: _size)` to initially set its location to center, `_size` is the offset your centered widget is located, something like: `50 * seize_of_each_widget`

Comment: can you add picture how do you want?

Comment: @NoobN3rd i thought of using that but that on its own causes another issue.

the inital list might be 10000 items long.

if we go by that route, the Listview.builder would be forced to actually build item 1 to 5001 on load and then programmatic ally scroll to to item number 5001.

im hoping to have all the lazyloadings of Listview.builder but start at the center of the list

Comment: @KirillMatrosov basically i want to have a scroll-able list that can be both scrolled up and down, and only load the items as needed

Comment: are you looking similar like this ; https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker

Comment: @AmitPrajapati no sir, im looking for something like a regular listview that just instead of loading items 1,2,3,4,5,6....1000,

instead it goes like skipped,skipped,skipped.... 500,501,502,502.... skipped, skipped skipped

that means scrolling up loads item number 499,498,497 while scrolling down loads 503,504,505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you could find any better solution, please let me know that.

If your list is infinite or very long you can set your first item to be the 5000th item and if you reached the first item(I mean when trying to see previous items) you should fetch(show) more data, like ..., 4998th 4999th.

The idea for scrolling is from [This blog](https://developpaper.com/flutter-loop-scroll-end-to-end-connection-stay-in-the-middle-view/)

I change your code to do the job, but consider that I am looking for a better solution, too.

Other widgets like: `ListWheelScrollView` and `PageView` can be used instead of listview if they fit in.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<int> nums;
  ScrollController ctrl;
  double start;
  bool isScroll = true;
  double end;

  @override
  void initState() {
    nums = List.generate(100, (i) => 4990 + i);
    ctrl = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 10 * 80.0)
      ..addListener(() {
        // fetch if ite reaches the end or start
        if (ctrl.offset == ctrl.position.minScrollExtent) {
          nums.insert(0, nums.first - 1);
          // ctrl.jumpTo(80.0 * 10);

          setState(() {});
        } else if (ctrl.offset == ctrl.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          nums.add(nums.last + 1);
          setState(() {});
        }
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (Notification notification) {
          if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
            start = notification.metrics.pixels;
            isScroll = false;
          } else if (!isScroll && notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
            end = notification.metrics.pixels;
            isScroll = true;

            double d = (end - start);
            // 80 is the items height
            double offset = d.abs() ~/ 80 * 80.0;
            if (d % 80.0 > 40) offset += 80.0;
            if (d.isNegative)
              ctrl.jumpTo(start - offset);
            else
              ctrl.jumpTo(start + offset);
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemExtent: 80.0,
          controller: ctrl,
          itemCount: nums.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('${nums[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

For fetching behavior it all depends on your preferences, you can do it if it is reached to the first item or the 10th one and then fetch new items, or instead of fetching(showing) one item per time do it 10 or so on.

Comment: wonderful wow, its a good starting for edits

thank you so much!!

im gonna see the framework itself, how does adding the items to be beginning of a listview.builder actually affects how it renders. ill try to see if it actually have to re-fetch the data for the previous entries or actually continues

Comment: i would like to confirm a couple of things

1. it seem like indeed the part of the minScrollExtent triggers a rebuild of the listview.builder itself thus all the items are lost
2. for the maxScrollExtent, it seems like a real listlist.builder that doesnt rebuild the listview.builder but instead increasing element count.

i shall get back as soon as possible if i find another approach with ur code as a starting point..

BRB

Comment: @anthonywiyono very good point thanks, yes I checked it [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26494) and You're right it rebuilds itself after using insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<int> nums;
  ScrollController ctrl;
  double start;
  bool isScroll = true;
  double end;
  bool allowScroll = true;
  RestartableTimer _timer = RestartableTimer(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {});

  @override
  void initState() {
    nums = List.generate(30, (i) => 4990 + i);
    ctrl = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 10 * 80.0)
      ..addListener(() {
        // fetch if ite reaches the end or start
        if (ctrl.offset == ctrl.position.minScrollExtent) {
          nums.insert(0, nums.first - 1);
          // ctrl.jumpTo(80.0 * 10);

          setState(() {});
        } else if (ctrl.offset == ctrl.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          nums.add(nums.last + 1);
          setState(() {});
        }
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (Notification notification) {
            if (notification is OverscrollNotification) {
              if (!_timer.isActive) {
                nums.insert(0, nums.first - 1);
                _timer.reset();
                setState(() {});
              }
            } else if (!isScroll && notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
              end = notification.metrics.pixels;
              isScroll = true;

              double d = (end - start);
              // 80 is the items height
              double offset = d.abs() ~/ 80 * 80.0;
              if (d % 80.0 > 40) offset += 80.0;
              if (d.isNegative)
                ctrl.jumpTo(start - offset);
              else
                ctrl.jumpTo(start + offset);
            }
            return true;
          },
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemExtent: 80.0,
            controller: ctrl,
            itemCount: nums.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print('build tile index $index');
              return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text('${nums[index]}'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hi guys

I have reworked the solution given by NoobN3rd that allow almost seemless loading that doesnt involve reloads frequently

this is by no means the perfect solution as you can see on the console, there seem to be a rebuild nonstop.

But i think this is a good enough solution for the time being.

RestartableTimer is the key to this solution. without it, OverScrollNotification inserts new items to the list way too fast

thank you again everyone for the help

Comment: i think the last step is to fix the rebuild and see if we can persist the listview